# Customizing WSO2 API Manager Responses

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I am playing around with WSO2 API Manager and was wondering how to take care of below scenario:

I have created a REST API and enabled JWT token on it. When calling the API, if I don't pass the token I am getting the error but in XML format. I was wondering how and where can we change that to a JSON format.

```
<ams:fault xmlns:ams="http://wso2.org/apimanager/security">
  <ams:code>900901</ams:code>
  <ams:message>Invalid Credentials</ams:message>
  <ams:description>Access failure for API: /employee/1.0.0, version: 1.0.0 status: (900901) - Invalid Credentials. Make sure you have provided the correct security credentials</ams:description>
</ams:fault>
```

Update:

I went to runtime configuation and tried to update the Message Mediation in Fault Section to JSON Fault but when saving I can see the below exception. The fault does not change.

```
[2020-01-19 11:50:09,596] ERROR - APIUtil Issue is in accessing the Registry
[2020-01-19 11:50:09,596] ERROR - APIMappingUtil Error occurred while getting the uuid of the mediation sequence
org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.api.APIManagementException: Issue is in accessing the Registry
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.utils.APIUtil.getMediationPolicyAttributes_aroundBody322(APIUtil.java:5438) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl_6.5.349.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.utils.APIUtil.getMediationPolicyAttributes(APIUtil.java:5373) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl_6.5.349.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.rest.api.publisher.v1.utils.mappings.APIMappingUtil.getMediationPolicyAttributes(APIMappingUtil.java:2360) [classes/:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.rest.api.publisher.v1.utils.mappings.APIMappingUtil.fromAPItoDTO(APIMappingUtil.java:754) [classes/:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.rest.api.publisher.v1.impl.ApisApiServiceImpl.apisApiIdPut(ApisApiServiceImpl.java:654) [classes/:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.rest.api.publisher.v1.ApisApi.apisApiIdPut(ApisApi.java:583) [classes/:?]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_231]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_231]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_231]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_231]
        at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.performInvocation(AbstractInvoker.java:179) [cxf-core-3.2.8.jar:3.2.8]
        at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:96) [cxf-core-3.2.8.jar:3.2.8]
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:193) [cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs-3.2.8.jar:3.2.8]
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:103) [cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs-3.2.8.jar:3.2.8]
        at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:59) [cxf-core-3.2.8.jar:3.2.8]
        at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:96) [cxf-core-3.2.8.jar:3.2.8]
        at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308) [cxf-core-3.2.8.jar:3.2.8]
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121) [cxf-core-3.2.8.jar:3.2.8]
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:267) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.2.8.jar:3.2.8]
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:234) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.2.8.jar:3.2.8]
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:208) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.2.8.jar:3.2.8]
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:160) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.2.8.jar:3.2.8]
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:216) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.2.8.jar:3.2.8]
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:301) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.2.8.jar:3.2.8]
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doPut(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:237) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.2.8.jar:3.2.8]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:663) [tomcat-servlet-api_9.0.22.wso2v1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:276) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.2.8.jar:3.2.8]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) [tomcat_9.0.22.wso2v1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat_9.0.22.wso2v1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) [tomcat_9.0.22.wso2v1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat_9.0.22.wso2v1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat_9.0.22.wso2v1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) [tomcat_9.0.22.wso2v1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat_9.0.22.wso2v1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490) [tomcat_9.0.22.wso2v1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) [tomcat_9.0.22.wso2v1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat_9.0.22.wso2v1.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.context.rewrite.valve.TenantContextRewriteValve.invoke(TenantContextRewriteValve.java:80) [org.wso2.carbon.identity.context.rewrite.valve_1.3.6.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.authz.valve.AuthorizationValve.invoke(AuthorizationValve.java:100) [org.wso2.carbon.identity.authz.valve_1.3.6.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.auth.valve.AuthenticationValve.invoke(AuthenticationValve.java:74) [org.wso2.carbon.identity.auth.valve_1.3.6.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:99) [org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext_4.5.1.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:49) [org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext_4.5.1.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:62) [org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext_4.5.1.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:146) [org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext_4.5.1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:678) [tomcat_9.0.22.wso2v1.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:57) [org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext_4.5.1.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.RequestCorrelationIdValve.invoke(RequestCorrelationIdValve.java:116) [org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext_4.5.1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) [tomcat_9.0.22.wso2v1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [tomcat_9.0.22.wso2v1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408) [tomcat_9.0.22.wso2v1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat_9.0.22.wso2v1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:853) [tomcat_9.0.22.wso2v1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1587) [tomcat_9.0.22.wso2v1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat_9.0.22.wso2v1.jar:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [?:1.8.0_231]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [?:1.8.0_231]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat_9.0.22.wso2v1.jar:?]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_231]
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.exceptions.ResourceNotFoundException: Resource does not exist at path /_system/governance/apimgt/customsequences\fault
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.handlers.builtin.MountHandler.get(MountHandler.java:449) ~[org.wso2.carbon.registry.core_4.5.1.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.handlers.HandlerManager.get(HandlerManager.java:2446) ~[org.wso2.carbon.registry.core_4.5.1.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.handlers.UserDefinedHandlerManager.get(UserDefinedHandlerManager.java:199) ~[org.wso2.carbon.registry.core_4.5.1.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.handlers.HandlerLifecycleManager.get(HandlerLifecycleManager.java:915) ~[org.wso2.carbon.registry.core_4.5.1.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.EmbeddedRegistry.get(EmbeddedRegistry.java:512) ~[org.wso2.carbon.registry.core_4.5.1.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.caching.CacheBackedRegistry.getGhostResourceFromCache(CacheBackedRegistry.java:225) ~[org.wso2.carbon.registry.core_4.5.1.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.caching.CacheBackedRegistry.get(CacheBackedRegistry.java:198) ~[org.wso2.carbon.registry.core_4.5.1.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry.getInternal(UserRegistry.java:617) ~[org.wso2.carbon.registry.core_4.5.1.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry.access$400(UserRegistry.java:61) ~[org.wso2.carbon.registry.core_4.5.1.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry$5.run(UserRegistry.java:597) ~[org.wso2.carbon.registry.core_4.5.1.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry$5.run(UserRegistry.java:594) ~[org.wso2.carbon.registry.core_4.5.1.jar:?]
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_231]
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry.get(UserRegistry.java:594) ~[org.wso2.carbon.registry.core_4.5.1.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.utils.APIUtil.getMediationPolicyAttributes_aroundBody322(APIUtil.java:5392) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl_6.5.349.jar:?]
        ... 57 more
[2020-01-19 11:50:09,599] ERROR - GlobalThrowableMapper An unknown exception has been captured by the global exception mapper.
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.rest.api.publisher.v1.utils.mappings.APIMappingUtil.fromAPItoDTO(APIMappingUtil.java:756) ~[classes/:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.rest.api.publisher.v1.impl.ApisApiServiceImpl.apisApiIdPut(ApisApiServiceImpl.java:654) ~[classes/:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.rest.api.publisher.v1.ApisApi.apisApiIdPut(ApisApi.java:583) ~[classes/:?]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_231]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_231]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_231]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_231]
        at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.performInvocation(AbstractInvoker.java:179) ~[cxf-core-3.2.8.jar:3.2.8]
        at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:96) ~[cxf-core-3.2.8.jar:3.2.8]
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:193) [cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs-3.2.8.jar:3.2.8]
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:103) [cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs-3.2.8.jar:3.2.8]
        at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:59) [cxf-core-3.2.8.jar:3.2.8]
        at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:96) [cxf-core-3.2.8.jar:3.2.8]
        at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308) [cxf-core-3.2.8.jar:3.2.8]
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121) [cxf-core-3.2.8.jar:3.2.8]
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:267) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.2.8.jar:3.2.8]
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:234) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.2.8.jar:3.2.8]
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:208) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.2.8.jar:3.2.8]
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:160) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.2.8.jar:3.2.8]
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:216) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.2.8.jar:3.2.8]
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:301) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.2.8.jar:3.2.8]
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doPut(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:237) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.2.8.jar:3.2.8]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:663) [tomcat-servlet-api_9.0.22.wso2v1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:276) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.2.8.jar:3.2.8]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) [tomcat_9.0.22.wso2v1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat_9.0.22.wso2v1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) [tomcat_9.0.22.wso2v1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat_9.0.22.wso2v1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat_9.0.22.wso2v1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) [tomcat_9.0.22.wso2v1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat_9.0.22.wso2v1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490) [tomcat_9.0.22.wso2v1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) [tomcat_9.0.22.wso2v1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat_9.0.22.wso2v1.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.context.rewrite.valve.TenantContextRewriteValve.invoke(TenantContextRewriteValve.java:80) [org.wso2.carbon.identity.context.rewrite.valve_1.3.6.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.authz.valve.AuthorizationValve.invoke(AuthorizationValve.java:100) [org.wso2.carbon.identity.authz.valve_1.3.6.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.auth.valve.AuthenticationValve.invoke(AuthenticationValve.java:74) [org.wso2.carbon.identity.auth.valve_1.3.6.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:99) [org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext_4.5.1.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:49) [org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext_4.5.1.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:62) [org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext_4.5.1.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:146) [org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext_4.5.1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:678) [tomcat_9.0.22.wso2v1.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:57) [org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext_4.5.1.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.RequestCorrelationIdValve.invoke(RequestCorrelationIdValve.java:116) [org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext_4.5.1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) [tomcat_9.0.22.wso2v1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [tomcat_9.0.22.wso2v1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408) [tomcat_9.0.22.wso2v1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat_9.0.22.wso2v1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:853) [tomcat_9.0.22.wso2v1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1587) [tomcat_9.0.22.wso2v1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat_9.0.22.wso2v1.jar:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [?:1.8.0_231]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [?:1.8.0_231]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat_9.0.22.wso2v1.jar:?]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_231]
```

Update 2:

referring to this doc, I was able to get the messgage in JSON format
https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM260/Error+Handling

Update 3:

Now how can I change the payload structure ?

Well what i really want is to change

```
{ "fault": { "code": 900901, "message": "Invalid Credentials", "description": "Access failure for API: /employee/1.0.0, version: 1.0.0 status: (900901) - Invalid Credentials. Make sure you have provided the correct security credentials" }}
```

the default message payload to something like this

```
{ "status": "fault", "description":{ "code": 900901, "message": "Invalid Credentials", "description": "Access failure for API: /employee/1.0.0, version: 1.0.0 status: (900901) - Invalid Credentials. Make sure you have provided the correct security credentials" }}
```

Comment: Please take a look at the payload factory mediator. https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB500/PayloadFactory+Mediator#PayloadFactoryMediator-Example2:JSON